# Combining elements in Python

Tags: python, list, element

I'm very new to Python, so perhaps I stumbled across the answer and didn't realize it, but I have searched and experimented with code all day and I'm still stumped regarding the following:

Given the following two lists:

```
List1 = [1, 2, 3]
List2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How would you create List3?

```
List3 = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
['{}{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> ['%d%s' % item for item in zip(l1, l2)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you hear about [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)?

```
[str(i)+j for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Example:

```
>>> List1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> List2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [str(i)+j for i,j in zip(List1,List2)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```